# Наложение текста на фотографию

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap

Подскажите, как наложить текст на изображение  с помощью bootstrap, пишу на html.

Comment: Рекомендую изучить возможности CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю все просто. Вы задаете родительскому блоку `backgroung-image` и внутри блока создаете блоки с текстом

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer__section">
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

В данном примере вам нужно задать изображение как фон для `footer` или `footer__section`

Comment: Спасибо большое 1

Comment: @Axel отметь это как ответ если помогло